# Is taking snapshot equivalent to inbuilt image in openstack?

Tags: cloud, openstack

I have encountered this question in my course's quiz. I've searched it everywhere but still not found any appropriate answer.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH9RG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question in the image would option **1: After installation of an instance**.
An Image is uploaded to the glance using "glance image create --[option]". Where a snapshot is taken from a running instance using "nova image-create --[option]". Both are same from usage perspective. 
Please follow this blog for better understanding:[Difference between Image and Snapshot](http:////https://ibm-blue-box-help.github.io/help-documentation/glance/imagesnapshot/)